# Cannot use Wi-Fi with USB tethering

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, usb, wireless-adapter

I was trying to activate USB tethering on my Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian 9 installed. Whenever I add the following to my **/etc/network/interfaces** and reboot, the Pi won't connect to my Wi-Fi and the Wi-Fi icon says "no wireless interface found".

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet dhcp
```

My stock **/etc/network/interfaces** looks like

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

I tried the same on Kali Linux RPi3 image, and it worked fine.

Comment: USB tethering is the same as a usb ethernet and thanks to NetworkManager, any time an ethernet is detected wifi won't be used.  You can, however, change the metric by adding the following in /etc/network/interfaces under "iface wlan0" add: "up ifmetric wlan 10"
and under "iface usb0 inet" add "up ifmetric usb0 20"